# How to remove blue focus border from TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

I'm styling a TableView. I set the border color to white (same as background color) so it is invisible. However, when the table is focused, the border becomes blue. I tried adding `table-view:focused { -fx-border-color: white; }` to fix it, but it didn't help. How do I fix this?

I didn't add a screenshot because when I hit `Print Screen` the Table loses focus.

Below is my full stylesheet, if it's relevant:

```css
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .column-header .filler,
.table-view .column-header-background .filler {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-font-size: 16px;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-color: #efefef;
}

.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-alignment: center_left;
    -fx-font-size: 16pt;
    -fx-padding: 5 0 15 0;
}

.table-row-cell,
.table-row-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.table-row-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #efefef;
}

.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.table-view .table-cell {
    -fx-border-color: efefef;
    -fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-padding: 5 3 15 3;
}

.table-view {
    -fx-border-color: white;
}

.table-view:focused .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Comment: try table-view:focus instead table-view:focused

Comment: `.table-view { -fx-focus-color: transparent; }`

Comment: `table-view:focus` didn't work. 
`-fx-focus-color: transparent` did something odd - the focus border becomes _slightly_ thinner, but it remains there. I assume there's another element that's adding up to the border, besides `focus-color`?

Comment: why do you want to confuse your users?

Comment: I tested it now and you are right @Allen Juan. You can add `-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;`as well. It takes some time to get used to the default [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way:

```
.table-view:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
}
```

I used for focused table-view the same declarations as for non focused one- see https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470#file-modena-css-L618

Answer (score 0):

the blue border added to your table should be removed if you use the outline css property and set it to none.
So , here set the outline : none for your table when focused.

```
.table-view:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: This makes the outline very very thin, but is still there. Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you provide your code in a jsfiddle, would like to see what's happening and why.

Comment: The question is about JavaFX CSS!